# error: ‘ItemStatus’ has not been declared

Tags: c++

In global.h

```
enum class ItemStatus {
    INQUEUE,
    FINISHED,
    PAUSE,
    STOP,
    RUNNING
};
```

in downloaditem.h

```
class DownloadItem
{
Private:
        ItemStatus status;
public:
   void setItemStatus(const ItemStatus _status)  { this->status = _status; }
};
```

Comment: And `global.h` have been included in `downloaditem.h`? Or before `downloaditem.h` is included?

Comment: have you tried including the global.h before the downloaditem.h ?

Comment: yes in downloaditem.h file i included global.h

Comment: @aminmoradian Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem as required here please. `Private` is wrong BTW. As well leading underscore is.

Comment: Use forward declarations